# change block region using template_preprocess_block() not working?

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I'm trying to move a block from the content region to the sidebar region if the page is not the front page. I would think this would be fairly simple. I have the following code:

```
<?php
    function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
        if($variables['is_front'] == FALSE) {
            if($variables['block']->bid == 39) {
                $variables['block']->region = 'sidebar';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This doesn't work. I can look at the array dump in Theme Developer and it does say `sidebar`, but the block isn't actually moved from the content region to the sidebar region when I inspect the rendered HTML.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Make sure you're using the theme as default and the you defined this in `template.php` and you cleared the cache.

Comment: I would recommend to use [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) + [rules bonus pack](https://drupal.org/project/rb) -> [see that tutorial](http://drupalize.me/videos/rules-bonus-pack-using-rules-presentation-altering) or alternatively [context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module for that. You can't change block region in preproces_block function.

Comment: I tried the Context module, and it seemed very complicated for such a simple task; it almost seems like Context is trying to replace the need for the `template.php` file. I will have a look at the Rules module. I was also looking at trying to change the block region through `hook_page_alter()`, but I found the documentation very confusing as to how to target a specific block. Thanks for pointing out those modules.